# Internal Server Error after changes in files

Tags: centos, ssh

I am using ssh to connect my host on server (connect via myaccount@ip). However, whenever I make changes in files on server, I see Internal Server Error everywhere. In fact, this happens whenever I commit something to my server using Eclipse svn plugin.

Here is apache2 log

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/myaccount/public_html/web/index.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://***
Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://***
```

I solve this problem via following commands (connect server via root account)

```
chown -R myaccount:myaccount /home/myaccount/public_html/
chmod -R 0755 /home/myaccount/public_html/
```

Do I have to connect via root and run commands above everytime I change something on my hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to set the permissions of the files in question to 755 (or your preferred group-unwritable set) with your normal account, since the files should still be owned by that account. To fix the issue permanently, try putting "umask 0227" in your .bashrc.